# Did Miriam remarry Joel a second time?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-marvelous-mrs-maisel

In the series *The Marvellous Mrs Maisel* Miriam and Joel divorce some time before the events of Season 3 Episode 4 "Hands!", after splitting up over Joel's infidelity. Then, in that episode, they briefly remarry and then divorce.

We know from Season 5 that Joel and Miriam remain close and that they regularly worship together at the synagogue. In a closing scene from the series, their (original?) wedding photo is prominently displayed - but do they ever remarry again?

Comment: Joel died, apparently: https://ew.com/tv/the-marvelous-mrs-maisel-series-finale-rachel-brosnahan-interview/?utm_source=twitter.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=social-share-article&fbclid=IwAR09vFWoOY5AYg82hbW_OvCm1LCRcFe-ZTiedqjArqyvMA3MAGfLJbxL5YM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They didn't marry a third time

[*Looper:*](https://www.looper.com/1258553/the-marvelous-mrs-maisel-who-are-midges-three-famous-ex-husbands/)

> Episode 2 of "The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel" Season 5, meanwhile, features a fictional "60 Minutes" segment all about Midge's storied career and legacy. The segment, notably, reveals that Midge did eventually remarry after her and Joel's divorce. According to the sequence, she didn't just marry a couple of unknown men, either. Instead, it turns out that **Midge went on to marry none other than Paul Simon, Robert Evans, and Quincy Jones.**

[*Amazon Advisor*](https://amazonadviser.com/2023/06/03/midge-four-husbands-the-marvelous-mrs-maisel/) confirms that the arithmetic rules out a third marriage to Joel:

> We know Joel is one of the four husbands—and he is only counted once! It doesn’t seem like the two remarry by the end, either. In her final act, Midge says that she’s not sure she will ever remarry, but we know she will. **She almost marries Philip Roth but decides not to at the last minute.**

### Joel is forever a marked man and will never put Midge in danger

Joel makes a pact to transfer Midge's debt to the mobsters to him, a debt he will be working off until he is finally caught and jailed. **He would never weaken that pact by remarrying Midge and merging their financial affairs.**